# polymorphism in user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

So I made a user control that has a custom `ScrollBar` and to left of it there is a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`. Is there a way to make the `DataGridView` polymorphic? Since I have many classes that inherit from the `DataGridView`, and it would be simpler to only have one `Control` which allows me to input multiple types of `DataGridView`s.

Comment: If you are creating these user controls in code, you could pass one of your inherited DataGridView objects in the constructor.  Then in the constructor, you can do this.fillPanel.Controls.Add(gridView);  gridView.Dock = Dock.Fill;  or something similar.  I've done this in the past.

Comment: Assuming your user control has a scrollbar on the right, and a panel that is set to Dock = Dock.Fill;